# How do we do Shabbat Hagadol Drasha at home

Tags: shabbat, passover, synagogue, choleh-sick

Because of the Corona virus synagogues are closed this week Tzav 5780 which is Shabbat Hagadol, we will not be able to fulfill the custom of a Shabbat Hagadol Drasha (sermon) according to the usual way. What is the correct way to fulfill the custom in this situation?
(Discussion of sources would improve an answer)

Answer (score 3):

Multiple rabbis in various communities that I'm aware of either live-streamed their sermon on Thursday night or recorded themselves delivering it and sent out the recording on Thursday night or Friday.

Comment: I know one who livestreamed on Sunday

Comment: I am looking for a discussion of sources. What day, if any, is best day for Shiur. Does this fulfill minhag (under circumstances) or is it simply next best. Does it count as tashlumin on Sunday?

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi Sorry; all I've got is a bunch of real-life examples. The question post indicates that sources are preferred, not that they're required.